# External Web Module in Eclipse EE Helios

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, context.xml

When I try to add an **external** web module into Tomcat, I observe the server.xml under
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/conf has been added

```
<Context docBase="C:\App1" path="/App1" reloadable="true"/>
```

However, all the settings (Resource) under META-INF/context.xml do not take effect, thus I can't connect to my database. I have to explicitly add resource settings under the server.xml.

```
<Context docBase="C:\App1" path="/App1" reloadable="true">
<Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
...
</Context>
```

Does anyone face the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource context is added automatically in Eclipse Indigo (3.7) after I upgraded my Eclipse version.